# putting records from gridview into rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am stuck with problem :

i have filled gridview from store procedure. This gridview has complaints being received and user has to select whether these are valid or invalid and then upon selecting Valid Complaints it must be presented in report. 
In simple words, Select 3 complaints as valid and click generate report and it should contain those 3 records.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateFrom.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
            DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateTo.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
            DataTable dt = ManageRecievedMessage.GetSmsComplaintsByDate(fromDate, toDate);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {

                dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
                int totalcolums = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = totalcolums;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found for this date combination";
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = false;
            HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "NoDataForInput";
            HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
        }

    }
    protected void GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //This Event is Triggered When Page is Changed in Gridview e.g. 1,2,3

        DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateFrom.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateTo.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
        DataTable dt = ManageRecievedMessage.GetSmsComplaintsByDate(fromDate, toDate);

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            GridViewSmsComplaints.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
        }
    }

 &nbsp;&nbsp; Date From:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp; Date To:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderDateFrom"  Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDateFrom" 
                              runat="server"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderDateTo"  Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDateTo" 
                              runat="server"></asp:CalendarExtender>

                            &nbsp;
   <span id="Save-Span">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Search" 
      ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupTextboxes" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                            <br />
   <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"  Width="550px">
               <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
                    <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FromMobileNo" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message" DataField="Message" >   
                     <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlValidity" runat="server">
                           <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Valid"></asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="InValid"></asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

i know about reporting etc but how to put selected as valid records in report ?

Comment: Is the valid field stored in the DB, or what you need is to do it on the fly, i.e. keep that value in memory and pass it to the report?

Comment: yes it should be stored, upon clicking Generate Report